# How to put a formula / equation into a text (not separate from the text and not centered)

Tags: math-mode

- How to put a formula into a text (not centralized)?
- I only know how
  to use `\[...\]` that places the formulas centralized, out of text.

Comment: Try `$...$` instead of `\[...\]`.

Comment: If you are very new to TeX then you can decide if LaTeX is best practice how to use TeX. There are another possibilities: ConTeXt, OpTeX, plain TeX.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 6):

- It seems like you are very new to LaTeX.
- I strongly suggest that you read an introduction in LaTeX rather than googling bit by bit, see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11).
- Overleaf has a good enough introduction to mathematical expressions, see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/mathematical_expressions.
- Personally, I recommend reading a recent book about LaTeX when you are starting using LaTeX.
- Regarding your question, what you are asking for is called **inline** mode and can be achieved by using the `$` command, as in `Normal text $a^2+b^2=c^2$ more normal text`.
- The other mode is called **display** mode (you called it "out of text").